# Visual Studio 2017 csc.exe exited with code -2146232797

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I try to rebuild my solution it gives me an error that says

```
"csc.exe" exited with code -2146232797.
```

I tried to delete the package folder and rebuilt it; it restored all the files but still gives me this error. Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: This is the error description: COR_E_FAILFAST (0x80131623): Runtime operation halted by call to System.Environment.FailFast. Check if this Roslyn issue helps: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4615.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue. 
i fixed like this

Install-package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -version 2.2.0

Comment: the csc erro is gone but it shows a missing assembly build error for all the namespaces, even for a project from scratch